# Computing dihedral angles using mdtraj

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import mdtraj as md
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import nglview as ngl

traj0 = md.iterload('xtc_file', chunk=1000, top='pdb_file')

def xyz_gen(traj):
    for chunk in traj:
        yield chunk.xyz

dihedrals = md.compute_dihedrals(traj0, indices)
```

Everything runs fine, but when I try to do the last step, I get:

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'xyz'.
```

What's causing this?

Comment: Please make sure you're posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your problem involves the fact that `chunk` is a generator and doesn't have an `xyz` attribute, but without context, it's impossible to say more about what's going on.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just edited the question, hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: Please include the full stack trace (the lines before the error message itself, saying where it came from). Also, a MRE should be something we can copy and paste, then run, to *reproduce* the error. I've not used this module before, but it seems you'd need to provide trajectory and topology files (short samples, not a huge chunk of real data). And you're not using or referencing that generator at all in the code supplied, so if it's relevant, you haven't shown how.